# how to change color of equal signs in richtextbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, richtext

I want to change color of equal sign as it happens in notepad++ while the user writes the text . My code is working but the cursor is stuck on one place and user cannot write anything in between the text it only allows to write it in the end , also does not detect when newline is present after =. How to do it ?

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{ 
    equal();     
}

public void equal()
{ 
    start = richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1;
    length = 1;

    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start;
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = length;
    string settext = richTextBox1.SelectedText;

    if ( settext ==Convert.ToString('='))
    {   
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Purple;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add event to your richtext box for  text changed:

private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ChangeColor("=", Color.Purple);

    }



private void ChangeColor(string word, Color color)
{
    if (this.richTextBox1.Text.Contains(word))
    {
        int index = -1;
        int selectStart = this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart;

        while ((index = this.richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word, (index + 1))) != -1)
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Select((index), word.Length);
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = color;
            this.richTextBox1.Select(selectStart, 0);
            this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! alot @amitdayam

Answer (score 1):

Please use the richTextBox_TextChanged event for changing the color. I have met this problem once in my application.